# Automatically copy files from desktop to USB drive when connected

Tags: windows-xp, usb, windows-vista

My problem is similar to [Automatically copy files to USB drive when connected](https://superuser.com/questions/22766/automatically-copy-files-to-usb-drive-when-connected).

However, the path of source of the file, which is the desktop, isn't static, so I want the solution to be able to automatically detect the path of the desktop of the current user, because I want to use the USB drive on too many PCs and and I can't select the desktop or specify the path manually.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps a portable sync program installed on the USB drive? But I think you're aiming a little high here, interesting though! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use %HOMEPATH%\Desktop as your source path. I believe that is correct for XP and up.

Comment: Another question, please. How can I make the destination path contains the time-date, so files from different PCs don't mix up?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`** as the path. Best of all is that this will work with the `XCOPY` solution, as the batch file will evaluate the environment variables.

Comment: What is the advantage of using %USERPROFILE%\Desktop over %HOMEPATH%\Desktop? Or are they the same thing? Thanks +1

Comment: Some applications may not allow %HOMEPATH% as it starts with a backslash when they expect a drive letter instead. %USERPROFILE% starts with C:\. Both will be fine if using XCOPY though as cmd will evaluate a backslash as the root of the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on Internet access/Permissions etc. have you considered using [Dropbox](http://getdropbox.com)? Cloud file storage that seamlessly integrates with Explorer/Finder and syncs files across all systems. Needs a small client install, but otherwise it's a great way to keep multiple systems up to date.

You can also install a portable version of the client called [DropboxPortable](http://wiki.getdropbox.com/DropboxAddons/DropboxPortable) onto a USB thumbstick and sync files across all accounts.