# Automatically launch a program on a freshly connected USB flash drive

Tags: windows, usb, external-hard-drive, application-launch

I have a Kingston DataTraveler USB flash drive. To access the encrypted partition, I have to launch the `DTVP_Launcher.exe` application in the root directory of the unencrypted, readonly partition.

There's an `autorun.inf` file that would launch the program, but running programs on USB is disabled by a group policy.

On the Mac there is [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) that elegantly solves the [same problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5988/automatically-launch-a-program-on-a-freshly-connected-usb-flash-drive). [AlternativesTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/marcopolo/) lists only programs to change network settings, but AFAICT nothing that can be triggered by an USB event.

Is there a way with Windows to launch a specific application automatically whenever I plug in a given USB stick?

Comment: I think autorun is disabled for USB flash drives on Windows 7

Comment: @m28 I know that autorun is no option and a security risk. I envision a background program that acts only on the connection of a specific USB drive, not any drive.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/22766/automatically-copy-files-to-usb-drive-when-connected/133839#133839

Comment: Writing a script isn't particularly hard, but that would defeat the purpose of having autorun disabled if it autoruns something. You'd have to verify the EXE using something like MD5, which is a bit harder.

Comment: @Zoredache Couldn't find any event in the EventViewer for an USB insertion. Is this *Portable Device Enumerator Service* mentioned in your link specific for Windows 7 (I'm stuck with Vista)?

Comment: @digitxp Writing a script shouldn't be too hard indeed, maybe even with MD5. But how would you trigger the execution of the script? Or would you poll every few seconds?

Comment: Looking from my research, the [PortableApps Autoplay](http://portableapps.com/node/13770?page=1) one, waits for an event, so there has to be some way...